# Connecting to IMAP server using libcurl

Tags: windows, imap, libcurl, winsock2, gmail-imap

I maintain an IMAP application (Windows), written in VC 2017, that uses Winsock2 for the underlying connection. I am investigating using libcurl instead of Winsock in order to relieve myself of various issues such as proxies and SSL/TLS, etc.

I am aware of the high level IMAP functions in libcurl but I don't want to go there, I need more direct control of IMAP and I need to re-use my existing code. So I would like to experiment with curl_easy_send() and curl_easy_recv().

So far not having much luck.  I'm basically running the demo program sendrecv.c that comes with libcurl (my slightly modified version shown below).

When you connect to an IMAP server it immediately sends back a response listing its capabilities. The client does not need to request it. In my program, I can connect to my test server (outlook.office365.com), and if I use port 143, the insecure IMAP port, I can receive the response.  But if I use secure port 993, the program hangs on the select() command, timing out after 60 seconds.

So presumably I have a problem with SSL.  I've tried enabling SSL using CURLOPT_USE_SSL, but it makes no difference. What am I missing here?

P.S. possibly an unrelated question, but when I try to connect to imap.gmail.com, the connection fails with error 56 (CURLE_RECV_ERROR).

```
static int wait_on_socket(curl_socket_t sockfd, int for_recv, long timeout_ms)
{
    struct timeval tv;
    fd_set infd, outfd, errfd;
    int res;

    tv.tv_sec = timeout_ms / 1000;
    tv.tv_usec = (timeout_ms % 1000) * 1000;

    FD_ZERO(&infd);
    FD_ZERO(&outfd);
    FD_ZERO(&errfd);

    FD_SET(sockfd, &errfd); /* always check for error */

    if (for_recv) {
        FD_SET(sockfd, &infd);
    }
    else {
        FD_SET(sockfd, &outfd);
    }

    /* select() returns the number of signalled sockets or -1 */
    printf("starting select\n");
    res = select((int)sockfd + 1, &infd, &outfd, &errfd, &tv);
    printf("finished select, res=%d\n", res);
    return res;
}


int main()
{
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;
    int port = 993;
    curl_socket_t sockfd;
    char imap_host[256] = "";
    char buf[1024];
    size_t nread;

    printf("Starting sendrecv demo\n");

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (!curl) {
        printf("Unable to initialize curl\n");
        return(0);
    }

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_DEBUGFUNCTION, debug_function);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

    //strcpy_s(imap_host, "imap.gmail.com");
    strcpy_s(imap_host, "outlook.office365.com");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, imap_host);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CONNECT_ONLY, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PORT, port);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USE_SSL, CURLUSESSL_TRY);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    printf("Return from connect: %d\n", res);

    /* Extract the socket from the curl handle - we'll need it for waiting. */
    res = curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_ACTIVESOCKET, &sockfd);
    if (res != CURLE_OK) {
        printf("Error getting socket\n");
        return(0);
    }

    printf("Reading IMAP response\n");

    while (1) {
        /* Warning: This example program may loop indefinitely (see above). */
        
        do {
            nread = 0;
            res = curl_easy_recv(curl, buf, sizeof(buf), &nread);

            if (res == CURLE_AGAIN && !wait_on_socket(sockfd, 1, 60000L)) {
                printf("Error: timeout.\n");
                return(0);
            }
        } while (res == CURLE_AGAIN);

        if (res != CURLE_OK) {
            printf("Error: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));
            break;
        }

        if (nread == 0) {
            /* end of the response */
            break;
        }

        printf("Received %d bytes\n", nread);
        buf[nread] = 0;
        break;

    }

    printf("response: %s\n", buf);

    /* always cleanup */
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

    return(0);


}
```

Comment: You are ignoring the return value of `curl_easy_perform()`, what is it actually returning? You are also not parsing the contents of `buf` at all, so you don't know when you have reached the end of the IMAP response and need to stop reading to avoid a false timeout trying to wait for more data that will never arrive.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  The return from curl_easy_perform is 0.  I didn't show it in my code, but I have the debug function displaying results, and it shows libcurl making a successful connection to the server.  At that point I call curl_easy_recv() and immediately get a return code of 81 (CURLE_AGAIN).  As per the example, I call wait_on_socket() with a timeout of 60 seconds.  That routine then hangs on the select() call until the timeout period.  Yes I do need to parse buf better in case I get data, but I do not. As I mentioned, this code works for port 143, but not 993.

Comment: I'm guessing curl is not actually sending an SSL/TLS handshake, but the server is waiting on your client to send one. That would explain the timeout issue. You are just going to have to sniff the network traffic to figure out what is really happening.

Comment: I was able to get it working by sticking "imaps://" in front of the server name.  Also had to disable CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER. The IMAP connection message comes in the debug_function which is different from when I use port 143, but it seems to be working enough I can proceed with testing.